# ScheduledExecutorService in an Android activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading

```
private ScheduledFuture<?> future;
private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);


Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
              //my code...

     }
};
future = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 15,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I have the aforementioned code in an android activity. So, I press a button and I go to the next activity. If I press the back button or explicitely (from a button) go to the previous activity again, is there any posibility a second timer to be created?

In other words, does the Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1) verifies me that the runnable will be executed only by one thread and that I will not have for example, two different tasks that both of them will run every 15 seconds?

Comment: if your first activity is not destroyed , then you will get the same instance and your task will be scheduled of appropriate time .

Comment: corePoolSize - is  the argument of the number of newScheduledThreadPool - threads to keep in the pool, even if they are idle.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html

```
    public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleAtFixedRate (Runnable command, long initialDelay, long period, TimeUnit unit)
```

Added in API level 1
Creates and executes a periodic action that becomes enabled first after the given initial delay, and subsequently with the given period; that is executions will commence after initialDelay then initialDelay+period, then initialDelay + 2 * period, and so on. If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed. Otherwise, the task will only terminate via cancellation or termination of the executor. **If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute.**

So, AFAIU the size of pool 1 and scheduleAtFixedRate ensure that there is only one thread running.

Answer (score -1):

I think that even if you switch Activities, your Runnable will keep running, since the activity context will be saved by the OS.

You should stop your thread when the Activity's onPause or onStop are called, by using:

```
future.cancel(true);
```

Then, if you come back to the activity you can schedule the Runnable again.

Comment: documentation of the shutdown method: Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted. Invocation has no additional effect if already shut down.

Comment: documentation for cancel: Attempts to cancel execution of this task. This attempt will fail if the task has already completed, has already been cancelled, or could not be cancelled for some other reason...So what I will do if the method doesn't cancel the thread???

Comment: I call Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(); in the onResume function, and then I call statusScheduler.shutdownNow(); in onPause. It works and when I come back to the activity, a new executor will be created and the runnable scheduled.